# SVG logo not displaying correctly on mobile

Tags: html, css, svg, adobe-illustrator

I've created the following SVG:

[image]

It is being correctly displayed on desktop, but the problem is on mobile. Here is a screenshot of how it is being displayed:

[image]

Here is the SVG:

```html
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 210.42 49.75">
    <defs>
    <style>
    .cls-1,.cls-3{font-size:48px;font-family:SHOOTING;}
    .cls-2{letter-spacing:-0.02em;}
    .cls-3{fill:#ffb857;}
    .cls-4{fill:#ff8f00;letter-spacing:0em;}
    </style>
    </defs>
    <title>logo</title>
    <g id="Capa_4" data-name="Capa 4">
    <text class="cls-1" transform="translate(41 41.79)">BUS<tspan class="cls-2" x="52.37" y="0">C</tspan><tspan x="68.78" y="0">AMINAS</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <g id="Capa_3" data-name="Capa 3">
    <text class="cls-3" transform="translate(42.76 40.32)">BUS<tspan class="cls-2" x="52.37" y="0">C</tspan><tspan x="68.78" y="0">A</tspan><tspan class="cls-4" x="87.17" y="0">MINAS</tspan></text>
    <path d="M34.69,19.49a1.27,1.27,0,0,0-.7-.72,1.29,1.29,0,0,0-1,0,11.93,11.93,0,0,0-4,2.63,12.08,12.08,0,0,0-2.63,4,1.29,1.29,0,0,0,0,1,1.26,1.26,0,0,0,.73.7,1.34,1.34,0,0,0,.49.1,1.28,1.28,0,0,0,1.25-.83,9.17,9.17,0,0,1,2-3.07,9.06,9.06,0,0,1,3.08-2,1.39,1.39,0,0,0,.72-.73A1.29,1.29,0,0,0,34.69,19.49Zm19.53-7.37,1,1-5.06,5,1.41,1.4a1.29,1.29,0,0,1,.4.95,1.26,1.26,0,0,1-.4.94L50.2,22.73a14.61,14.61,0,0,1,.69,12.78,14.32,14.32,0,0,1-7.77,7.77,14.55,14.55,0,0,1-11.34,0,14.69,14.69,0,0,1-4.66-3.11,14.75,14.75,0,0,1-4.26-10.33A14.26,14.26,0,0,1,24,24.17a14.58,14.58,0,0,1,20.55-7.08l1.32-1.33a1.31,1.31,0,0,1,.95-.39,1.29,1.29,0,0,1,.94.39l1.41,1.41ZM54.38,11a.63.63,0,0,1-.45.21.66.66,0,0,1-.48-.21L51.56,9.09a.72.72,0,0,1-.18-.48.67.67,0,0,1,1.14-.47L54.38,10a.61.61,0,0,1,.21.47A.59.59,0,0,1,54.38,11Zm4.77,4.77a.69.69,0,0,1-.95,0l-1.87-1.88a.63.63,0,0,1,0-.94.6.6,0,0,1,.47-.2.58.58,0,0,1,.46.2l1.89,1.87a.69.69,0,0,1,0,1Zm.85-3.8a.62.62,0,0,1-.19.48.65.65,0,0,1-.47.19h-2a.65.65,0,0,1-.67-.67.65.65,0,0,1,.19-.47.62.62,0,0,1,.48-.19h2a.65.65,0,0,1,.66.66ZM56,8v2a.66.66,0,1,1-1.32,0V8A.66.66,0,1,1,56,8Zm3.13,1.14L57.26,11a.61.61,0,0,1-.45.21.66.66,0,0,1-.48-.21.59.59,0,0,1-.21-.46.61.61,0,0,1,.21-.47L58.2,8.14A.64.64,0,0,1,58.67,8a.65.65,0,0,1,.67.66A.73.73,0,0,1,59.15,9.09Z" transform="translate(-22.86 -1.21)"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

Here is the HTML where I have the SVG:

```
 <div class="logo"><img src="./source/logo.svg" alt="Buscaminas" width="255px"></div>
```

Here is the CSS for the div:

```
.logo {
    height: 50px;
    width: 255px;
    margin: 10px auto 19px;
}
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Probably the text for the logo has tspans with x or dx attributes. in some cases the browser may change the font used and the text will appear crammed. Please update your question by adding the svg code for the logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've removed the x and y attributes of the `<tspan>` elements. This is fixing the problem with the crammed text. However since you are using a special font-family that is not disponible, the font-family is different and the text is wider. In order to get all the text inside the svg canvas I had to change the value of the viewBox. Probably a good idea would be using an alternative font-family, for example Arial.

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 360 60">
    <defs>
    <style>
    .cls-1,.cls-3{font-size:48px;font-family:SHOOTING, Arial;}
    .cls-2{letter-spacing:-0.02em;}
    .cls-3{fill:#ffb857;}
    .cls-4{fill:#ff8f00;letter-spacing:0em;}
    </style>
    </defs>
    <title>logo</title>
   <g id="wrapper">
    <g id="Capa_4" data-name="Capa 4">
    <text class="cls-1" x="41" y="41.79">BUS<tspan class="cls-2" >C</tspan><tspan>AMINAS</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <g id="Capa_3" data-name="Capa 3">
    <text class="cls-3" x="42.76" y="40.32">BUS<tspan class="cls-2" >C</tspan><tspan>A</tspan><tspan class="cls-4">MINAS</tspan></text>
    <path id="b" d="M34.69,19.49a1.27,1.27,0,0,0-.7-.72,1.29,1.29,0,0,0-1,0,11.93,11.93,0,0,0-4,2.63,12.08,12.08,0,0,0-2.63,4,1.29,1.29,0,0,0,0,1,1.26,1.26,0,0,0,.73.7,1.34,1.34,0,0,0,.49.1,1.28,1.28,0,0,0,1.25-.83,9.17,9.17,0,0,1,2-3.07,9.06,9.06,0,0,1,3.08-2,1.39,1.39,0,0,0,.72-.73A1.29,1.29,0,0,0,34.69,19.49Zm19.53-7.37,1,1-5.06,5,1.41,1.4a1.29,1.29,0,0,1,.4.95,1.26,1.26,0,0,1-.4.94L50.2,22.73a14.61,14.61,0,0,1,.69,12.78,14.32,14.32,0,0,1-7.77,7.77,14.55,14.55,0,0,1-11.34,0,14.69,14.69,0,0,1-4.66-3.11,14.75,14.75,0,0,1-4.26-10.33A14.26,14.26,0,0,1,24,24.17a14.58,14.58,0,0,1,20.55-7.08l1.32-1.33a1.31,1.31,0,0,1,.95-.39,1.29,1.29,0,0,1,.94.39l1.41,1.41ZM54.38,11a.63.63,0,0,1-.45.21.66.66,0,0,1-.48-.21L51.56,9.09a.72.72,0,0,1-.18-.48.67.67,0,0,1,1.14-.47L54.38,10a.61.61,0,0,1,.21.47A.59.59,0,0,1,54.38,11Zm4.77,4.77a.69.69,0,0,1-.95,0l-1.87-1.88a.63.63,0,0,1,0-.94.6.6,0,0,1,.47-.2.58.58,0,0,1,.46.2l1.89,1.87a.69.69,0,0,1,0,1Zm.85-3.8a.62.62,0,0,1-.19.48.65.65,0,0,1-.47.19h-2a.65.65,0,0,1-.67-.67.65.65,0,0,1,.19-.47.62.62,0,0,1,.48-.19h2a.65.65,0,0,1,.66.66ZM56,8v2a.66.66,0,1,1-1.32,0V8A.66.66,0,1,1,56,8Zm3.13,1.14L57.26,11a.61.61,0,0,1-.45.21.66.66,0,0,1-.48-.21.59.59,0,0,1-.21-.46.61.61,0,0,1,.21-.47L58.2,8.14A.64.64,0,0,1,58.67,8a.65.65,0,0,1,.67.66A.73.73,0,0,1,59.15,9.09Z" transform="translate(-22.86 -1.21)"/>
    </g>
   </g>
</svg>
```

UPDATE

In order to control the length of the text you can use the  `textLength` and `lengthAdjust` attributes like so:

```html
 <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 245 55">
    <defs>
    <style>
    .cls-1,.cls-3{font-size:48px;font-family:SHOOTING,Arial;}
    .cls-2{letter-spacing:-0.02em;}
    .cls-3{fill:#ffb857;}
    .cls-4{fill:#ff8f00;letter-spacing:0em;}
    </style>
    </defs>
    <title>logo</title>
   
    <g id="Capa_4" data-name="Capa 4">
    <text class="cls-1" x="41" y="41.79" textLength="200" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs">BUS<tspan class="cls-2" >C</tspan><tspan>AMINAS</tspan></text>
    </g>
    <g id="Capa_3" data-name="Capa 3">
    <text textLength="200" lengthAdjust="spacingAndGlyphs" class="cls-3" x="42.76" y="40.32">BUS<tspan class="cls-2" >C</tspan><tspan>A</tspan><tspan class="cls-4">MINAS</tspan></text>
    <path id="b" d="M34.69,19.49a1.27,1.27,0,0,0-.7-.72,1.29,1.29,0,0,0-1,0,11.93,11.93,0,0,0-4,2.63,12.08,12.08,0,0,0-2.63,4,1.29,1.29,0,0,0,0,1,1.26,1.26,0,0,0,.73.7,1.34,1.34,0,0,0,.49.1,1.28,1.28,0,0,0,1.25-.83,9.17,9.17,0,0,1,2-3.07,9.06,9.06,0,0,1,3.08-2,1.39,1.39,0,0,0,.72-.73A1.29,1.29,0,0,0,34.69,19.49Zm19.53-7.37,1,1-5.06,5,1.41,1.4a1.29,1.29,0,0,1,.4.95,1.26,1.26,0,0,1-.4.94L50.2,22.73a14.61,14.61,0,0,1,.69,12.78,14.32,14.32,0,0,1-7.77,7.77,14.55,14.55,0,0,1-11.34,0,14.69,14.69,0,0,1-4.66-3.11,14.75,14.75,0,0,1-4.26-10.33A14.26,14.26,0,0,1,24,24.17a14.58,14.58,0,0,1,20.55-7.08l1.32-1.33a1.31,1.31,0,0,1,.95-.39,1.29,1.29,0,0,1,.94.39l1.41,1.41ZM54.38,11a.63.63,0,0,1-.45.21.66.66,0,0,1-.48-.21L51.56,9.09a.72.72,0,0,1-.18-.48.67.67,0,0,1,1.14-.47L54.38,10a.61.61,0,0,1,.21.47A.59.59,0,0,1,54.38,11Zm4.77,4.77a.69.69,0,0,1-.95,0l-1.87-1.88a.63.63,0,0,1,0-.94.6.6,0,0,1,.47-.2.58.58,0,0,1,.46.2l1.89,1.87a.69.69,0,0,1,0,1Zm.85-3.8a.62.62,0,0,1-.19.48.65.65,0,0,1-.47.19h-2a.65.65,0,0,1-.67-.67.65.65,0,0,1,.19-.47.62.62,0,0,1,.48-.19h2a.65.65,0,0,1,.66.66ZM56,8v2a.66.66,0,1,1-1.32,0V8A.66.66,0,1,1,56,8Zm3.13,1.14L57.26,11a.61.61,0,0,1-.45.21.66.66,0,0,1-.48-.21.59.59,0,0,1-.21-.46.61.61,0,0,1,.21-.47L58.2,8.14A.64.64,0,0,1,58.67,8a.65.65,0,0,1,.67.66A.73.73,0,0,1,59.15,9.09Z" transform="translate(-22.86 -1.21)"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```